# Xamarin and Facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, xamarin

I'm looking for a solution on some problem.
    We have mobile app on Xamarin and requirement to sign in with Facebook credentials.
    To solve this we use Xamarin.Auth also tried CloudRail.
    In both cases it works but it needs to input credentials when you laungh app first time, then app remebmers and allow to use them again.
    Here is question. Maybe some one know how to skip that step, and login in app via Facebook with no one first time input credentials?
    Like in GMail or Shazam. You download app, click Sign in with Facebook and it does't requires to input credentials, it's already known.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
[Facebook Xamairn Components](https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents)
, which contains binding for Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android.